# Delayed Loading iframe is undefined?

Tags: iframe, delay, undefined

I have an iframe that I am loading after a 1.8 second delay using a javascript css change of visibility:hidden to visibility:visible.

The script below works for Safari and FF, but when the script runs in IE most of the text is gone and I get the (possibly unrelated?) error "iframe is undefined".

What can I do?

```
    <iframe src="PAGE INCLUDED" 
name="childframe" id="childframe" class="childframe" 
scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" 
style="width: 176px; height: 3000px; overflow:hidden; border: none; visibility:hidden;"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function() {  
    $('iframe.childframe').css("visibility", "visible")
}, 1800); // delays 1.8 sec
</script>
```